# How to turn off spelling check?

Tags: html, reactjs, input, textarea, grammarly

I have the input attribute set up as follows and used both of them one at a time but didn't work out.

```
spellCheck="false"  or 
spellCheck={false}
```

Later, I found that the Grammarly extension on the browser automatically added and set the whole page spell-checking attribute to true. How to stop the grammar check-in input field?

Comment: If you are looking to disable Grammarly, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46777787/10664939) may help

Comment: @LoganAnderson,  I tried all of them but no luck yet